# Deleting records in multiple SQL tables at once (with outer join!)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables (t1 and t2), and t2 has **zero** or more rows that have a FK to t1's primary key.  Note the zero rows which requires an OUTER JOIN.

I wish to delete the record in t1 corresponding to a given t1 primary key, and any related rows in t2.

I don't wish to use cascading deletes.

I've messed around with the following, but am not sure it is working.

Is this valid SQL?

Thanks

```
DELETE t1,t2
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t2.t1_id=t1.id
WHERE t1.id=123;
```

Comment: @GeniaS.  Thanks.  I saw these, but they seem to pertain to inner joins.  If an outer join doesn't match, is the first table's record still deleted?

Comment: @GeniaS.  Me neither, thus the question.  I know how to deal with inner joins.  Hopefully, my question will not be closed without an answer.

Comment: AFAIK you cant do it with single query, u dont want to cascade delete nor seperate queries. i'll search for this

Comment: @marathonman  I've implemented it, and it seems to work perfect.  Before going to production, would be good to know for sure!

Comment: This question asks about deleting multiple tables with an `outer join`, the other question is about a single table with an `inner join`.  Hard to see how this question duplicates the older one.

Comment: Yes, it is a valid statement.

Comment: @Al-mo A valid statement? It's a logical fallacy.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer - yes, this is valid SQL. The same considerations when deleting using an inner join apply to outer joins too.